# how to determine rows making determinant of matrix nearly singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have a 10*10 matrix, whose determinant is -3.8985e-07 (approximately zero). When I reduce it echelon form, it shows me complete rank. I am not sure which row is causing it to be approximately singular.

My matrix is as follow:
**A** = \begin{matrix}
0.0426  &  0.0032 &    0.0029 &    0.0264 &   -0.0094 &    0.3868  & -0.1292  &  0.1259 &   0.0417  &  0.3669 \\
    0.0007 &   0.0006 &  -0.0121 &  -0.0594 &   0.0142 &   0.2541  &  0.4486    & 0.0034 &   -0.5867 &  -0.0168 \\
   -0.0010 &    0.0061 &   -0.0297 &  -0.1211  &  0.0662   & 0.1349 &  -0.2580     & 0.0180  & -0.2322 &    0.0887 \\
   -0.0027 &   0.0170  & -0.0838 &  -0.3270   & 0.2099 &   0.2917  & -0.7196   & -0.5922  &  2.7905   & 0.5151 \\
  0.0001  & -0.0004 &   0.0019   & 0.0078 &  -0.0048  & -0.0158 &   0.0212  &  0.0410  & -0.0650 &   5.6639 \\
    0.0010 &    0.0002 &  -0.0203 &   -0.0481 &   0.0529 &   -1.1830 &   0.4618  &  3.6336   & 0.5938 &  -2.3641 \\
    0.0141  &  0.0036  & -0.0024 &    0.0187 &   0.0117  & -0.0099  & -0.0129    & 0.0097  &  0.0079 &   0.0031 \\
   -0.0006  &  0.0016 &  -0.0010  &  0.0005 &   0.0124 &   -0.0010 &   0.0164    & 0.0137  & -0.0221  & -0.0110\\
    0.0096 &  -0.0162  & -0.0020 &   -0.0046 &   -0.0012 &  -0.0026 &  -0.0002   & -0.0008 &   -0.0001 &    0.0001\\
   -0.0411 &   0.0951  & -0.0257 &   0.0668  &  0.8981 &  -1.8226  & -2.7494  &  0.9926 &   5.6168  & -0.7285 \end{matrix}

The above matrix is generated by the following procedure:

```
A = [JEE*M^{-1};  
     JOr*M^{-1};  
     JCOM*M^{-1};  
     M^{-1}(9,:)]
```

Value of JEE, JOr, JCOM and  M^{-1} are given on link
https://pastebin.com/dmRP4xKj

JEE = \begin{matrix}
 0.4116  &  0.0509 &   0.1475 &   0.3754  &  0.0214 &   0.3278 &  -0.0762 &   0.1872  &  0.0406 &        0\\
  0 &  -0.0000 &  -0.3059  & -0.0131 &    0.2994 &    0.0997 &    0.2411 &   -0.0044 &  -0.0024  &       0 \\
   -0.1073 &  -0.4639 &   -0.2431 &   -0.0589 &   -0.0014 &   -0.0507 &  -0.2808   & 0.0389  & -0.1958 &         0  \end{matrix}

Jor = \begin{matrix}
  0   &     0 &  -0.8549  & -0.0276 &   0.6819 &   0.3221  &  0.9272 &  -0.1869 &   0.9788 &    0.0248 \\
    1.0000   & 1.0000 &  -0.0000 &  -0.9986 &  -0.0521 &  -0.8741 &    0.3688 &    0.3049 &   -0.0228  &  0.9997 \\
   -0.0000 &  -0.0000  & -0.5187  &  0.0455  & -0.7296 &   0.3635 &    0.0652 &   0.9339 &   0.2033 &  -0.0072  \end{matrix}

JCOM = \begin{matrix}
 0.1918 &    0.0938  &  0.0407 &   0.0265 &   0.0182 &    0.0158 &  -0.0044  &  0.0057 &    0.0012 &        0 \\
         0    &     0  & -0.0208 &  -0.0012  &  0.0260 &   0.0053   & 0.0129 &   -0.0002 &   -0.0001 &         0 \\
    0.0337 &  -0.1232  & -0.0670 &  -0.0104 &    0.0151 &  -0.0012 &   -0.0107  &   0.0012 &   -0.0059    &     0  \end{matrix}

M_inverse = \begin{matrix}
0.1093 &   -0.0904   & 0.0477 &  -0.1160  & -0.0937  &  0.1243 &   0.1222 &  -0.0806 &  -0.0720 &  -0.0295 \\
   -0.0765 &   0.2780 &  -0.3772 &   0.6788  &  0.0228  & -0.5932  & -0.2216 &   0.0015   & 0.0951  &  0.0558 \\
    0.0382 &  -0.3772 &   1.3700 &  -3.4682 &    0.3792 &   3.2918  & -0.3330  & -0.0489  & -0.0257  & -0.0975 \\
   -0.0428 &   0.6788 &  -3.4682 &  12.9593  & -0.4682 &  -13.8475  &  2.4026 &   2.2228   & 0.0668  & -1.3056 \\
   -0.0478 &   0.0228 &   0.3792 &   -0.4682 &   1.3084 &  -0.7536  & -0.7630 &   1.4545   & 0.8981  & -1.1341 \\
    0.0857 &  -0.5932 &   3.2918 & -13.8475 &  -0.7536 &  18.6303  & -2.4133  & -5.9961  & -1.8226  &  5.5496 \\
    0.0717 &  -0.2216 &  -0.3330   & 2.4026 &  -0.7630  & -2.4133  &  3.5014  &  0.8804   & -2.7494  & -1.2524 \\
   -0.0426 &   0.0015 &  -0.0489 &   2.2228   & 1.4545 &  -5.9961   & 0.8804 &   6.9075   &  0.9926  & -5.2356 \\
   -0.0411 &   0.0951  & -0.0257 &   0.0668  &  0.8981  & -1.8226 &  -2.7494 &    0.9926   & 5.6168  & -0.7285 \\
   -0.0174 &   0.0558 &  -0.0975 &  -1.3056 &  -1.1341 &   5.5496 &  -1.2524 &   -5.2356  & -0.7285 &  11.1710 \end{matrix}

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. The problem is coming from JCOM*M^{-1} term. I tried finding the pseudo inverse of every term and determinant of $\left(JCOM*M^{-1}\right)*\left(JCOM*M^{-1}^{T}\right)^{T}$ has determinant very close to zero. So I believe the near singularity must be coming from it.